# Is there any possibility to create commit message templates on azure DevOps repositories?

Tags: git, azure-devops, pre-commit

I just want to create some standard commit messages for repositories, is this feature available? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

You can add code into your [`.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg`](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_prepare_commit_msg) hook that will alter message in the way you want:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

COMMIT_MSG_FILE=$1

# Only add custom message when there is no commit source
# ($COMMIT_SOURCE is empty). Otherwise, keep the default message
# proposed by Git
if [[ -z "$COMMIT_SOURCE" ]]
then
    echo "Default message template goes here" > "$COMMIT_MSG_FILE"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, this is applicable only client-side, right? I'm looking for something on the Azure DevOps side

Comment: @CGE If your DevOps are making commits, then you can write script with template.

Comment: @CGE: you cannot change a commit once it is made. Whatever person or software makes the commit chooses the commit message, which then stays the same forever. (You can make a *different* commit, as a new-and-improved replacement to be used instead, but the original commit remains unchanged.) If you're making the commit on AzDO, you'll need to set up the commit message on AzDO; if you're using `git commit` to do that, the hooks will work as usual; if not, you'll need to investigate whatever you're using to make those commits.